# Based on a rows value decide which column to use? Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Say I have a dataframe like below.

```
eff_month  eff_date  latest_volume_month_1  latest_volume_month_2  latest_volume_month_3  pct

  1        2022-01-13      55                        60                   70               .5
  2        2022-02-10      40                        50                   60               .1
  3        2022-03-02      30                        50                   70               .2
```

How can I dynamically select which column to use depending on the row? For example.
For the first row I would like to select the "latest_volume_month_1" column.

I've tried this so far to no avail.

```
F.col(f"latest_volume_month_{F.col('eff_month')}")
F.col("latest_volume_month_{}".format(F.col('eff_month')))
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by requirement is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`when` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.when.html#pyspark.sql.Column.when) with condition that will define what column to use, like this:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

select(F.when(F.col("eff_month") == 1, F.col("latest_volume_month_1")\
  .when(F.col("eff_month") == 2, F.col("latest_volume_month_2")
...
)
```

although it could look cumbersome and hard to write manually, you can use code to generate this select column, with like this (using loop):

```py
cl = None
for i in range(1,10):
  if cl is None:
    cl = F.when(F.col("eff_month") == i, F.col(f"latest_volume_month_{i}"))
  else:
    cl = cl.when(F.col("eff_month") == i, F.col(f"latest_volume_month_{i}"))
cl = cl.alias("name_of_result_column")
```